# Trying to efficiently delete records in table which has multicolumn index

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I am using MySQL 5.6 on Linux (RHEL). The database client is a Java program. The table in question (MyISAM or InnoDB, have tried both) has a multicolumn index comprising two integers (id's from other tables) and a timestamp.

I want to delete records which have timestamps before a given date. I have found that this operation is relatively slow (on the order of 30 seconds in a table which has a few million records). But I've also found that if the other two fields in the index are specified, the operation is much faster. No big surprise there.

I believe I could query the two non-timestamp tables for their index values and then loop over the delete operation, specifying one value of each id each time. I hope that wouldn't take too long; I haven't tried it yet. But it seems like I should be able to get MySQL to do the looping for me. I tried a query of the form

```
delete from mytable where timestamp < '2013-08-17'
    and index1 in (select id from foo)
    and index2 in (select id from bar);
```

but that's actually slower than

```
delete from mytable where timestamp < '2013-08-17';
```

Two questions. (1) Is there something I can do to speed up delete operations which depend only on timestamp? (2) Failing that, is there something I can do to get MySQL to loop over two other two index columns (and do it quickly)?

I actually tried this operation with both MyISAM and InnoDB tables with the same data -- they are approximately equally slow.

Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this problem.

EDIT: More info about the table structure. Here is the output of `show create table mytable`:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `fooId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `barId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `baz` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `quux` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fooId` (`fooId`,`barId`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14221944 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='stuff'
```

Here is the output of `show indexes from mytable`:

```
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
|mytable|          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |     2612681 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
|mytable|          0 | fooId    |            1 | fooId       | A         |          20 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
|mytable|          0 | fooId    |            2 | barId       | A         |        3294 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
|mytable|          0 | fooId    |            3 | timestamp   | A         |     2612681 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

EDIT: More info -- output from "explain".

```
mysql> explain delete from mytable using mytable inner join foo inner join bar where mytable.fooId=foo.id and mytable.barId=bar.id and timestamp<'2012-08-27';
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo   | index | PRIMARY       | name    | 257     | NULL                          |   26 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bar   | index | PRIMARY       | name    | 257     | NULL                          |   38 | Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      |mytable| ref   | fooId         | fooId   | 8       | foo.foo.id,foo.bar.id         |  211 | Using where                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you also post some information about the table structure "show create table" command

Comment: @RaymondNijland: I have added output from show create table and show indexes from. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: And the tables foo and bar? But the problem is that you want to delete an large selection this means that your BTREE indexes need to be updated als well and this will slow down your deletes. i don't know how many records your selections matches maybe you can also run an count(*)  note this can take about 5 or 10 minutes on an large innodb table.

Comment: And select count(*) from mytable using mytable inner join foo inner join bar where mytable.fooId=foo.id and mytable.barId=bar.id and timestamp<'2012-08-27' returns how many records  because the row column is an estimate with the InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the multiple-table `DELETE` syntax to join the tables:

```
DELETE mytable
FROM   mytable
  JOIN foo ON foo.id = mytable.index1
  JOIN bar ON bar.id = mytable.index2
WHERE  timestamp < '2013-08-17'
```

I think that this should perform particularly well if `mytable` has a composite index over `(index1, index2, timestamp)` (and both `foo` and `bar` have indexes on their `id` columns, which will of course be the case if those columns are PK).

Comment: Yes, id is a primary key for foo and bar, and (index1, index2, timestamp) is a composite key for mytable. I tried the query as you suggested, but unfortunately I found that it is not any faster. Thank you all the same for the suggestion, I appreciate it.

Comment: @RobertDodier: Could you include in your question the `EXPLAIN` plan?

Comment: I have put output from "explain" into the question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the other two ids. Add an index just on the time stamp. Otherwise you may be traversing the whole table.

Comment: thanks for your response. I don't quite understand what you mean. The uniqueness constraint is important to the meaning of the table. Do you mean, add another index on just the timestamp? I don't know if that's possible. Maybe I've misunderstood what you're getting at; perhaps you can clarify.

Comment: 'Add an index just on the timestamp' is exactly what I said. I don't see how that possibly be misunderstood. It is certainly possible technically. Make it non-unique of course. You may have dbadmin problems getting it done, but as it solves this performance problem there is really no room for dispute.